# Aggregate values in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

After performing multi-level filtering inside Pig, I get the below results -

```
(2343433,Argentina,2015,Sci-Fi)
(2343433,France,2015,Sci-Fi)
(2343433,Germany,2015,Sci-Fi)
(2343433,Netherlands,2015,Sci-Fi)
(2343433,Argentina,2015,Drama)
(2343433,France,2015,Drama)
(2343433,Germany,2015,Drama)
(2343433,Netherlands,2015,Drama)
(2343433,Argentina,2015,Family)
(2343433,France,2015,Family)
(2343433,Germany,2015,Family)
(2343433,Netherlands,2015,Family)
```

The column names are movieid,country,year and genre respectively. I need to aggregate these results and produce something like this -

```
(2343433,France,2015,Sci-Fi,Drama,Family)
(2343433,Germany,2015,Sci-Fi,Drama,Family)
(2343433,Netherlands,2015,Sci-Fi,Drama,Family)
(2343433,Argentina,2015,Sci-Fi,Drama,Family)
```

Either that or something like this -

```
 (2343433,France,Germany,Netherlands,Argentina,2015,Sci-Fi,Drama,Family)
```

Below is my code to get the above results -

```
A = LOAD '/user/a1.csv' USING PigStorage('|') as (movie_id,movie_name,prod_year);
B = LOAD '/user/a2.csv' USING PigStorage('|') as (g_movieid,genres);
C = LOAD '/user/a3.csv' USING PigStorage('|') as (c_movieid,country_released);
D = JOIN A by movie_id, B by g_movieid;
E = JOIN D by g_movieid, C by c_movieid;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE movie_id,country,year,genre;
```

Any idea on how to achieve this using Pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
Dump F;
(2343433,Argentina,2015,Sci-Fi)
(2343433,France,2015,Sci-Fi)
(2343433,Germany,2015,Sci-Fi)
(2343433,Netherlands,2015,Sci-Fi)
(2343433,Argentina,2015,Drama)
(2343433,France,2015,Drama)
(2343433,Germany,2015,Drama)
(2343433,Netherlands,2015,Drama)
(2343433,Argentina,2015,Family)
(2343433,France,2015,Family)
(2343433,Germany,2015,Family)
(2343433,Netherlands,2015,Family)


G = GROUP F BY (movie_id, country, year);
H = foreach G generate FLATTEN(group) as (movie_id, country, year), $1.$3 AS (genre:{T:(value:chararray)});
I = foreach H generate movie_id, country, year, FLATTEN(BagToTuple(genre.value));
Dump I;

(2343433,France,2015,Sci-Fi,Drama,Family)
(2343433,Germany,2015,Sci-Fi,Drama,Family)
(2343433,Argentina,2015,Sci-Fi,Drama,Family)
(2343433,Netherlands,2015,Sci-Fi,Drama,Family)
```